# Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0

Tags: java, maven, aem

I am working on an AEM project and facing the below error while building my maven project.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on project acs.core: Execution generate-scr-scrdescriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr failed: **Could not load the propery file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml' (check CLASSPATH)** -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on project acs.core: Execution generate-scr-scrdescriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr failed: Could not load the propery file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml' (check CLASSPATH)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution generate-scr-scrdescriptor of goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr failed: Could not load the propery file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml' (check CLASSPATH)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Could not load the propery file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml' (check CLASSPATH)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.OutputPropertiesFactory.getDefaultMethodProperties(OutputPropertiesFactory.java:345)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.setDefaults(TransformerImpl.java:1168)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.createOutputProperties(TransformerImpl.java:1129)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.<init>(TransformerImpl.java:270)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.<init>(TransformerImpl.java:261)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:764)
    at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.xml.IOUtils.parse(IOUtils.java:59)
    at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.xml.ComponentDescriptorIO.read(ComponentDescriptorIO.java:167)
    at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.helper.ClassScanner.readServiceComponentDescriptor(ClassScanner.java:527)
    at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.helper.ClassScanner.readServiceComponentDescriptor(ClassScanner.java:558)
    at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.helper.ClassScanner.getComponentDescriptors(ClassScanner.java:497)
    at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.helper.ClassScanner.getDescription(ClassScanner.java:433)
    at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.SCRDescriptorGenerator.createComponent(SCRDescriptorGenerator.java:397)
    at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.SCRDescriptorGenerator.execute(SCRDescriptorGenerator.java:161)
    at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.mojo.SCRDescriptorMojo.execute(SCRDescriptorMojo.java:237)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :acs.core
```

Not sure from where it's referencing the "output_xml.properties" file.

Comment: Could you try changing the maven-scr-plugin artifact version to 1.22.0 and rebuild the project?

Comment: Also it seems that your system is not consistently using the same Java version. Please check that both `echo $JAVA_HOME` and `mvn -v` output the same java version.

Comment: @iusting Yes, you are right! Different Java versions were the issue.  I am facing a different issue now, would you be able to look into that, please?  Link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974290/maven-build-failing-because-of-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-felixmaven-bu                        Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin plugin,  use this plugin, it has to be declared in the project descriptor as a  element:

```
<project>
...
<build>
...
<plugins>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>scr</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
...
</build>
...
</project>
```

If you want to process the standard annotations with the maven-scr-plugin add this dependency:

```
<project>
...
<dependencies>
...
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
     <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.ds-annotations</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.4</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
...
</dependencies>
...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks Mayank for your reply. I am already using this plugin. I am not sure if this error is related to some "output_xml.properties" file.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer by a few months but I was able to resolve my error by doing an import and extending my class with SlingAllMethodsServlet

```
...
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
...

public class Something extends SlingAllMethodsServlet ....{
    ...
}
```